# How do I restrict file upload to only .xlxs and .docx files

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload, knockout.js

I am working on a file upload functionality which should only allow .xlxs and .docx  files. At the moment with the code below I am able to limit uploads to .xlsx only. I would however like to also upload .docx files but it seems my piece of code is preventing the .docx files from being uploaded.

```
 if (files.length > 0) {

      if (files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.docx') === -1 || files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.xlsx') === -1) {
         $.msgbox("Please note: only excel file formats are allowed. Please download the provided upload template, see the link below.");
         this.value = '';
         return;
      }
```

So that code above should spit out anything that is not xlsx or docx but the problem is it is spitting out docx as well

Comment: Think your wording needs to change, do you want docx or not?

Comment: I do want docx I have edited my question apologies for the typo

Comment: I think you mean to do && instead of ||

Comment: Do keep in mind that this isn't secure in any way.  So make sure your server side post handler for the file upload also checks the file type.

Generally, I won't do the check client side at all, I'll have an API that has methods to tell me what file types are allowed and I'll poll it as the user selects files and remove the invalids based on the server response and if they hack the JS the api will throw an error on the invalid type.  Client side validation is a user experience, not secure at all, have to do it again server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try your code like this:

```
if (files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.docx') === -1 && files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.xlsx') === -1) {
     $.msgbox("Please note: only excel file formats are allowed. Please download the provided upload template, see the link below.");
     this.value = '';
     return;
}
```

You're checking if it's not docx AND it's not xlsx, not OR

Answer (score 4):

You can list restricted file types right in the HTML code:

`<input type="file" accept=".xlxs,.docx">`

Comment: The accept attribute is a convenience for the user in that it filters the file selection popup, but it does not prevent the user from selecting any file they would like to. You have to actually check what they selected.